# OpenGL linking issue with vs2017

Tags: opengl, linker

I'm trying to link openGL library's with visual studio 2017. in the linker i included some library's and headers but it gives me the following errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A000040) "extern "C" void __cdecl gluPerspective(double,double,double,double)" (?gluPerspective@@$$J0YAXNNNN@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __clrcall OpenGLForm::COpenGL::ReSizeGLScene(int,int)" (?ReSizeGLScene@COpenGL@OpenGLForm@@$$FIE$AAMXHH@Z)   Graphical Arduino Windows Controller    C:\Users\dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project1\Project1\Viewport.obj  1
```

also this one

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl gluPerspective(double,double,double,double)" (?gluPerspective@@$$J0YAXNNNN@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __clrcall OpenGLForm::COpenGL::ReSizeGLScene(int,int)" (?ReSizeGLScene@COpenGL@OpenGLForm@@$$FIE$AAMXHH@Z)    Graphical Arduino Windows Controller    C:\Users\dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project1\Project1\Viewport.obj  1
```

and also

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  Graphical Arduino Windows Controller    C:\Users\dani\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project1\x64\Debug\Graphical Arduino Windows Controller.exe 1
```

Anyone know how to resolve these linker issues?

Comment: You mentioned that you have included some libraries and headers. Can you be more specific what libraries that you have already added as input and how?

Comment: Yes, i includedglew32.lib glew32s.lib glfw3.lib flgw3dll.lib and OpenGL32.lib

Comment: oh and for the headers i includedthe GL, GLFW and GLM headers. i've added all of these as dependancies.

Comment: If you want to use glu* function you need to link against glut or freeglut. glu functions are not part to the OpenGL API.

Comment: You need to include glu32.lib too.